# Is there a way to read the browser's cookie from a java applet?

Tags: java, cookies, applet

I have a java applet that needs to do http requests to the server. A quick experiment showed that the session id cookies from the browser is not sent along, so i'll have to set it manually. 
Currently, I see 2 possible solutions:

- somehow get hold of the cookie data from within the applet
- pass the cookie information into the applet's contructor via javascript

I'd prefer the first solution, but i wasn't able to find a working solution for that. all information i found (mostly netscape.javascript.JSObject) were outdated (my 1.5 VM does not have this class)

Any great ideas or resources i have not yet found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your JVM doesn't contain this class? You should look in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/plugin.jar`. I found it in my 1.5.0_14 installation.

If you are generating the page dynamically, you don't necessarily need to use JavaScript to communicate the session ID. As long as you know it server-side, you can place it into an applet parameter tag in the generated HTML which contains the `<applet>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays all browsers are supporting httponly cookies.If cookies are consciously set in server as 'httponly' in appropriate response headers,applets may not be able to access it.